# How to convert SQL query into LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

How can I convert the following SQL query into linq? This is what is tried

```
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SampleDateTime) AS Total
    FROM dbo.PrecisionArchive
    WHERE AgencySourceId = 7 AND EventType IN('R', 'ONS')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
var total = dbo.PrecisionArchive.Where(p => p.AgencySourceId == 7)
                                .Where(p => p.EventType == "R" || p.EventType == "ONS")
                                .Select(p => p.SampleDateTime)
                                .Distinct()
                                .Count();
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I had it that way originally, but thought this was more readable/maintainable, given the other requires use of parentheses.  Either works, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
var result = 
    (from x in dbContext.PrecisionArchive
     where x.AgencySource == 7 &&
           (x.EventType == "R" || x.EventType == "ONS")
     select x.SampleDateTime)
    .Distinct()
    .Count();
```

You could also try using `Contains` to represent the `IN` clause, but I don't believe this is supported by Linq-to-SQL:

```
var result = 
    (from x in dbContext.PrecisionArchive
     where x.AgencySource == 7 &&
           new[] { "R", "ONS" }.Contains(x.EventType)
     select x.SampleDateTime)
    .Distinct()
    .Count();
```

Comment: @DouglasBarbin No `Contains` like that _is_ supported by Linq-to-SQL. It will translate to an SQL `IN(...)`

Comment: My mistake.  In that case, `.Contains` would be the correct thing to use.